# vue3-Carousel scrolling issue with only two slides

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue3-carousel

I'm having an issue with wrap around scrolling when there are only two slides in the carousel. With the exact same setup, everything works correctly if there are three ore more slides, but with only two slides the carousel will only scroll Left to Right regardless of which navigation button I click or which direction I swipe. The order of the slides is correct, as is the pagination, it's just the animation that's incorrect. If I turn wrapAround scrolling off, I can correctly scroll the slides left or right, but with it turned on, they only scroll right. Here is the setup for the carousel and settings:

```
    <carousel :settings="settings" ref="carouselRef">
      <slide :key="index" v-for="(photo, index) of project.photos">
        <div class="pic-outer">
          <img
            class="pic"
            :src="photo"
            draggable="false"
          />
        </div>
      </slide>
      <template #addons>
        <pagination
          :style="{ opacity: project.photos.length == 1 ? 0.001 : 1 }"
        />
      </template>
    </carousel>

const settings = {
  itemsToShow: 1,
  itemsToScroll: 1,
  wrapAround: true,
};
```

This issue is occurring even if I place the carousel in an empty component with no styling, so I can't think of anything else that could be interfering. I'm curious if anyone has run into this before or if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by updating to the newest version of vue3-carousel.